# quadratic equation program output numbers

Tags: c++, equation, quadratic, sqrt

apologies for the wall of text.

I have been given the following task from the book I am working from:

"*Quadratic equations are of the form: a x^2 + b x + c = 0*

*To solve these, one uses the quadratic formula: (-b±√(b^2-4ac))/2a*

*There is a problem, though: if b^2-4ac is less than zero, then it will fail.
Write a program that can calculate x for a quadratic equation. Create a function that prints out the roots of quadratic equation given a,b,c.
When the program detects an equation with no real roots, have it print out a message. How do you know that your results are plausible? Can you check that they are correct?*"

I have wrote my program. But, all the outputs that I get are weird numbers. For example: 7.08141e+268. This is using 4 so the sqrt should be 2 I believe.

EDIT: I have amended the code and receive the correct values for the sqrt of a,b,c now. But, x1 and x2 are giving out nan which is just wrong. Hopefully this code is a bit cleaner and a better layout.

```
double quad_x1(double b, double a, double c) {
double x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 *a);
return x1;
}

double quad_x2(double b, double a, double c) {
double x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
return x2;
}

double square_root_a(double a) {
double sq_a=sqrt(a);
if(sq_a<0){
throw invalid_argument("Input is less than zero.");
}
else {
return sq_a;
}
}

double square_root_b(double b) {
double sq_b=sqrt(b);
if(sq_b<0) {
throw invalid_argument("Input is less than zero.");
}
else {
return sq_b;
}
}

double square_root_c(double c) {
double sq_c=sqrt(c);
if(sq_c<0) {
throw invalid_argument("Input is less than zero.");
}
else {
return sq_c;
}
}

int main ()
{
try{
double a=4;
double b=4;
double c=4;

double sq_a = square_root_a(a);
double sq_b = square_root_b(b);
double sq_c = square_root_c(c);
double x1 = quad_x1( b, a, c);
double x2 = quad_x2( b, a, c);

cout<<"The square roots are: a = "<<sq_a<<" b = "<<sq_b<<" c = "<<sq_c<<'\n';
cout<<"The answer to the quadratic is:\n";
cout<<"x1 = "<<x1<<'\n';
cout<<"x2 = "<<x2<<'\n';
}

catch (invalid_argument) {
cerr<<"Invalid Input - Less than zero"<<'\n';
return 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the output to your question

Comment: You need to assign the results of your function calls to the vars: `sq_a = square_root(a, b, c);`

Comment: Quite a few problems in your code, but the main one is that sq_a, sq_b and sq_c are never set to anything, hence the invalid undefined values that are being printed.

Comment: Your square_root function is never being called (you can check this by adding cout << "square_root called"; in the function, and anyway it does not return what you think it does. You should call it one time for each value a, b and c if you want to recover the square roots of each.

Comment: There's a bunch of things that could go wrong, but before that you should clean up your code: 1. Indent your code consistently. I'm not even going to look at it in any depth as it is now. 2. Reduce the scope of variables. Instead of creating them all at the beginning of main, declare and initialize them exactly at the point they are used. Never have variables that are not initialized with a value! 3. Remove the loop. 4. Remove the input (which can also fail!) and replace it with fixed values instead in order to create the requried minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call your functions.

> ```
>    double square_root(double a, double b, double c); //send values to sqrt check
>    double quad_x1(double b, double a, double c);    //send values to get x1
>    double quad_x2(double b, double a, double c);    //send values to get x2
> ```

These are **function declarations** for the functions already defined above. They have absolutely no effect. The functions are not called.

It's as if you had done this:

```
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    std::cout << "global\n";
}

int main()
{
   void f(); // just a declaration, f() is not called
}
```

Another problem is that you do not initialise `main`'s `sq_a`, `sq_b`, `sq_c`, `x1` and `x2` variables. Those variables are of type `double`. Trying to read from them is therefore **undefined behaviour**, which means your entire program is invalid.

You seem to have the misconception that variable names in C++ are always global. But that's far from the truth. Your `x1` in `main` has absolutely nothing to do with `x1` in `quad_x1`. You probably meant to do something like:

```
x1 = quad_x1(b, a, c);
```

And so on...

---

You should start with much **simpler programs** to learn C++. Calling a function and storing the result in a local variable is about the most basic thing you can do. Don't tackle quadratic equations until you get that right. Start with a program that uses a function to add two numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. And also the guys advice. I have amended my code which has solved my problem. This is my first time with functions but I now understand how to do it.

Comment: @MartinDickinson: You are welcome. However, on SO it's best practice to ask a *new* question rather than editing your original one. So I suggest you undo your edit and instead ask a new question referring (via a link) to this one.

Comment: @MartinDickinson: Just to make it clear: you now have a new problem, that's why a new question would be the right thing to do. But editing a question should only be done to clarify or better explain an existing problem.